# Можно ли избежать большого объема кода в условии if-else?

Tags: kotlin, if

Имеется задача: вывести null null, если входной String из двух слов получает "" или " ".

Я решил задачу таким образом:

```
if (fullText == "" || fullText == " ") {
    firstWord = null
    lastWord = null
} else if (firstWord == "" || firstWord == " ") {
    firstWord = null
} else if (lastWord == "" || lastWord == " ") {
    lastWord = null
}
```

Вопрос: Можно ли это сделать по-другому, не прибегая к такой массивной конструкции?

Comment: вместо таких строк if (fullText == "" || fullText == " ") используй if (fullText.isBlank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно , у вас несколько if-ов просто без причины.
Ибо если и первое слово и второе слово это пропуск, то общее слово получается пропуск, так что можно прописать и так ( На синтаксис не смотреть, ибо не проверялось, чекай логику)

```
  if (firstWord == "" || firstWord == " ") {
    firstWord = null
if (lastWord == "" || lastWord == " ") {
    lastWord = null
}}
```

Comment: Вложенность неправильная. Надо второй иф из первого вынуть.

Comment: Нет, если первый иф верный, то проверяется второй иф. Нам надо чтобы оба были нулл или не нулл

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, эти проверки можно заменить на .isBlank(), так как этот метод проверяет, если строка пустая или состоит из пробелов

```
if (firstWord.isBlank()) {
    firstWord = null
if (lastWord.isBlank()) {
    lastWord = null
}}
```

Comment: К сожалению, этот вариант мне не подошел. Почему-то в тестах дает краш, если isBlank

Comment: @AntonPankratov а с какой ошибкой падает?